# building docker image from dockerfile

Tags: docker

Here is my command in terminal to build image, `sudo docker build -t actinbox3.2:latest` .

I'm getting this error

```
" Step 0 : FROM iamdenmarkcontrevida/base
        Pulling repository iamdenmarkcontrevida/base
        INFO[0020] Repository not found"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
    # Dockerfile for base image of actInbox
    FROM iamdenmarkcontrevida/base

    MAINTAINER Denmark Contrevida<DMcontrevida@gmail.com>


    # Config files
    COPY config /actinbox_config/
    COPY script /actinbox_script/
    COPY database /actinbox_db/

    # Config pyenv
    RUN echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="/root/.pyenv"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
        echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
        echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
    # Config Nginx
        rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && \
        ln -s /actinbox_config/actinbox.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/actinbox.conf && \
    # Config PostgreSQL
        rm /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf && \
        ln -s /actinbox_config/pg_hba.conf /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf && \
    # Create DB & Restore database
        sh /actinbox_config/create_db_actinbox.sh && \
    # Delete template folder
        rm -r /actinbox_db/
```

**Mydockerfile in Base**

## Dockerfile for base image of actInbox

```
    FROM ubuntu:14.04

    MAINTAINER Denmark Contrevida<DMcontrevida@gmail.com> 

    # Base services
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        git nginx postgresql postgresql-contrib

    # Install Pyenv, Python 3.x, django, uWSGI & psycopg2
    COPY config/install_pyenv.sh /tmp/install_pyenv.sh
    RUN sh /tmp/install_pyenv.sh
```

Please help me out or any idea why im getting this error? I have an account in docker hub...........

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Basically, it can't find the `iamdenmarkcontrevida/base` image in dockerhub.

Did you build/push the base image?

```
docker build .
docker tag <local-image-id> iamdenmarkcontrevida/base:latest
docker push iamdenmarkcontrevida/base
```

Comment: What if i'll start from zero? like i want to update all software on my images.

Answer (score 1):

No need push, if you only need run it locally.

So you need build the base image first, then build `actinbox3.2`

For example (suppose you have different Dockerfile name)

```
sudo docker build -t iamdenmarkcontrevida/base -f Dockerfile.base
sudo docker build -t actinbox3.2 -f Docker.actinbox3.2
```

tag `latest` is default, so no need add it in build command.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a two line command -

1. Get your **local-image-id**

```
docker ps
```

2. Copy Names

```
docker build -t local-image-id/Any name you want:latest .
```

> For me
> `docker build -t condescending_greider/newdoc:latest .`

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

In directory Contain DockerFile run command prompt and then type:
`docker build -f Dockerfile ..`
It generate Id and use it into next command:
`docker tag Id imagename`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try packer framework
that is easiest way to create docker image.
it also supported many other type of machine image.

https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/index.html